# Keep correct view.frame.origin.y with autolayout

Tags: ios, ios7, uikit, interface-builder, autolayout

I'm trying to start using auto layout consistently in my projects but I can't get my head around it.

Here I have a `UIView` with 2 subviews:

[image]

I want it to stay like this in `retina 4 inch`, but I want to move the `view.frame.origin.y` 40 or 60 points up on the `3.5 inch` screen. Is there any way to do it with standard auto layout constraints?

Obviously, not using autolayout is not an option here.

I've tried putting different constraints up & down but they don't seem to give me the full control over the y values of the frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to use the [`UIViewController`'s `topLayoutGuide`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/topLayoutGuide). Please check out the [Apple's Technical Q&A QA1797 "Preventing the Status Bar from Covering Your Views"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1797/_index.html), hope this is exactly what you need.

## UPDATE

Sorry for not careful reading your question. I don't think you can have shift of y-coordinate by some arbitrary value for your view without runtime calculations. But you can achieve what you need by combination of the 2 constraints and modification of constraint values in the `viewDidLoad` method:

1. Control-drag from your label (which needs to be shifted up on 3.5" screen) to the `bottomLayoutGuide` and set vertical spacing constraint.
2. Control-drag from your label to itself and set height constraint for the label.

This gives you 88 pixels shift on 3.5" screen comparing to 4" screen. In the `viewDidLoad`, you can detect if device has 3.5" screen and increase the 1st constraint value by 20/40/60.

This is not a graceful solution but hope it helps.

Comment: No, the question has nothing to do with the status bar. Just need a reliable way to put the view 20/40/60 point up with autolayout